# What is the alternative in postgresql for Trancount in mssql

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

Iam migrating database from mssql to PostgreSQL.

MSSQL Code:

```
begin try

   select * from tbl_name;

    <set of sql stmnts>
end try
begin catch
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0    
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
end catch
```

How can this be implemented in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You don't need it. When the block throws an error it will be rolled back automatically. There is nothing you need to do for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...